# Get result by id fails

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to use celery in my Flask-based web app and monitore it's state. My idea is to store task's id in session, and use it for state polling.

Here is content of my tasks.py

```
from traceback import format_exc
import settings
from celery import Celery, current_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery.result import AsyncResult

from nimble_auth import make_nimble_req

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

celery = Celery('tasks')
celery.config_from_object(settings)

@celery.task
def make_work(param1, param2):
    try:
        # work here
        current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS', meta={'current': page, 'total': total_pages})
    except StandardError:
        logger.error(format_exc())

def get_asynctask(task_id):
    return AsyncResult(task_id)
```

Except from main app's file web.py

```
@app.route('/task_state/<task_id>')
def task_state(task_id):
    return get_asynctask(task_id).state # from task.py

@app.route('/reset_task')
def reset_task():
    del session['celery_task_id']
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/run')
def run_task():
    task = make_work.delay(1, 2)
    session['celery_task_id'] = task.task_id
    flash('Task submitted OK!')

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Settings file:

```
BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dramba'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dramba'
```

But when I'm trying to get task's state, I'm getting NotImplementedError: No result backend configured.

Full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/GitHub/Dramba/dramba.py", line 13, in task_state
    return get_asynctask(task_id).state
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 284, in state
    return self.backend.get_status(self.id)
  File "/Users/cleg/Projects/Venvs/Dramba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 490, in _is_disabled
    raise NotImplementedError('No result backend configured.  '
NotImplementedError: No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I've swithed to redis as celery backend and used direct call to celery.backend.get_task_meta()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Flask itself doesn't pickup configuration properly from your file. Try specifying it explicitly and see if it helps: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#example-2-using-a-configuration-module

Also, just to be sure, are there any messages on stdout of Flask process?

Comment: Actually, solution was to pass celery instance to AsyncResult constructor as app parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS dictionary ? This page shows you an example:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#mongodb-backend-settings

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
*    "host": "192.168.1.100",
*    "port": 30000,
*    "database": "mydb",
*    "taskmeta_collection": "my_taskmeta_collection",
}
```

Comment: I've set CELERY_RESULT_DBURI — I thought it's the same. I've checked option with dictionary — it's the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's the same". I am not sure if you can use the CELERY_RESULT_DBURI for mongodb.

Comment: I've tried to specify information using settings dict, as you've suggested, but received same error "NotImplementedError: No result backend configured."

Comment: Ok. may be you can share the error stacktrace. The issue might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@app.route('/task_state/<task_id>')
def task_state(task_id):
    return celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id).state # from task.py
```

You need use current instance of Celery
Надо использовать уже существующий экземпляр Celery

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
app = Celery('anytaskname',backend="celery.backends.amqp:AMQPBackend")
```

It worked on Windows with Django 1.8 and Celery 3.1.25 with a RabbitMQ broker
[doc info](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/_modules/celery/backends.html)